# innodb_encrypt_tables = ON Convert table Collation

Tags: mariadb, encryption, mariadb-10.4

With Encryption at REST enabled on a MariaDB (10.4) database, can you change the Collation of all tables without unencrypting the database e.g:

alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci

OR does the database need to be decrypted before changing the collation?

Comment: Data encryption and  data collation are not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the ALTER TABLE statement cannot be done without reading the table, aka [ALGORITHM=INSTANT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#algorithminstant) ([proof by fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/atJGLLt5)) decryption will be performed as part of the alteration.

To validate the character set of existing data, and potentially convert it, and to reindex columns based on potentially a new collation, data does need to be read.

The data at rest encryption is transparent, so provided the key for the table is available it will happen automatically.